# Share a video to Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm writing a simple test app to upload a video to Facebook from iOS.

I'm finding it quite hard to find examples/tutorials online for how to do this with Swift since all the documentation for the FacebookSDK is in Objective-C.

I have this so far which puts a share button on my UI but it looks disabled, from what I have read this is because there is no content set but I can't see how that is possible.

```
    let video_content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()

    video_content.video = FBSDKShareVideo(videoURL: getVideoURL())

    let button : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
    button.shareContent = video_content

    button.frame = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100) * 0.5, 50, 100, 25)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

my `getVideoURL()` functions returns a NSURL which definitely contains the url to the video (I have printed it to console and checked it points to a video I have stored in a folder earlier).

I looked at the social framework and its a shame I can't use it because it seems it is only used for sharing photos and not able to share videos.

I'm using latest versions of Xcode, Swift and Facebook SDK.

Comment: I had EXACTLY same problem and I solved it!
Video URL should be from Library not your app so save your video and get url from library. then it will work.

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71435371/11079607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AngryDuck

Try this code it will work

```
func uploadVideoOnFacebook() {
    var pathURL: NSURL
    var videoData: NSData
    pathURL = NSURL(string: self.strUploadVideoURL)!
    videoData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(NSURL(string: self.strUploadVideoURL)!)
    NSString * strDesc
    strDesc = txtCaption.text!
    var videoObject: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["title": "application Name", "description": strDesc, pathURL.absoluteString(): videoData]
    var uploadRequest: FBRequest = FBRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: videoObject, HTTPMethod: "POST")
    self.view!.userInteractionEnabled = false
    uploadRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection: FBRequestConnection, result: AnyObject, error: NSError) -> Void in
        if !error {
            NSLog("Success")
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Error")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi i am getting FBSDKGraphRequestConnection cannot be started before Facebook SDK not initialized i have written a native code in swift for Flutter

Answer (score 9):

**converted into swift 3 and  4 :-**
**try this**

```
func uploadVideoOnFacebook() {
        var pathURL: URL
        var videoData: Data
        pathURL = URL(string: "Your video url string")!
        do {
            videoData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "Your video url string")!)
            print(videoData)
            var strDesc : String
            strDesc = ""
            let videoObject: [String : Any] = ["title": "application Name", "description": strDesc, pathURL.absoluteString: videoData]
            let uploadRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: videoObject, httpMethod: "POST")
            self.view!.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            uploadRequest.start(completionHandler: {(connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, result: AnyObject, error: NSError) -> Void in
                if error == error {
                    NSLog("Error")

                }
                else {
                    NSLog("Success")
                }
            } as! FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Comment: How to attach place/placeId?

Comment: It is working for me.But now i have an issue ,i can post video to my group.But i  can not post  video to other groups[if i am admin i can post otherwise i cannot], can you help me.

Comment: is it possiblr to post video to public groups

Comment: I get error like "No permission to publish the video". I have a developer role in FB app (Development mode). Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Using SDK Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

The video URL videoURL must be an asset URL. You can get a video asset URL e.g. from UIImagePickerController.

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import MobileCoreServices
import Photos

        func createAssetURL(url: URL, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
            let photoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
            var videoAssetPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
            photoLibrary.performChanges({
                let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url)
                videoAssetPlaceholder = request!.placeholderForCreatedAsset
            },
                completionHandler: { success, error in
                    if success {
                        let localID = NSString(string: videoAssetPlaceholder.localIdentifier)
                        let assetID = localID.replacingOccurrences(of: "/.*", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: NSRange())
                        let ext = "mp4"
                        let assetURLStr =
                        "assets-library://asset/asset.\(ext)?id=\(assetID)&ext=\(ext)"

                        completion(assetURLStr)
                    }
            })
        }

        func shareFacebbok() {
            let content: FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
            let videoURLs = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!
            createAssetURL(url: videoURLs) { url in
                let video = FBSDKShareVideo()
                video.videoURL = URL(string: url)
                content.video = video

                let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
                shareDialog.shareContent = content
                shareDialog.mode = .native
                shareDialog.delegate = self
                shareDialog.show()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in objective c and I had a similar problem. Do not know if this will work well for swift.

The problem was that if for some reason the video had to be stored in `NSDocumentDirectory` or `NSTemporaryDirectory` so she could work. Not if it's your case.

Although you can use in the worst case `FBSDKGraphRequest` with /me/Videos

I have come to see that this way of sharing videos that you are trying to use, get links directly from the library of photos. As you can see in [this example](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-share-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)

Currently only have example in `objective-c` i hope this can help you

```
- (void)uploadVideoWithoutSettingsCredentials:(NSURL *)videoUrl withTitle:(NSString *)title withDesc:(NSString *)desc withPrivacy:(NSString *)privacy
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0), ^{
        NSError * error = nil;

        NSData * videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl options:0 error:&error];
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4L];
        [params setObject:videoData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.MOV",title]];
        [params setObject:desc forKey:@"description"];

        NSString *privacyString = @"EVERYONE";
        if (privacy.length > 0)
            privacyString = privacy;

        NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: privacyString, @"value", nil];
        [params setObject:[Utils objectToJsonString:privacyDict] forKey:@"privacy"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"RESPONSE!!! /me/videos");
                NSLog(@"result %@",result);
                NSLog(@"error %@",error);

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (!error) {
                        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your clip was posted!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                    } else {
                        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                    }
                });
             }];
        });
    });
}
```

You can change to swift sintax, using Xcode autocomplete functionality.

You can help yourself a little with the syntax swift with [this](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)

Comment: The video I'm trying to upload is in documents directory, but i do also have the NSURL of where i have saved it into photo albums too, i tried that but still shows disabled as if i have set no media content? do you have an example of it working with graph request?

Comment: is it possible to post video public groups

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code in my app and this works fine for me.

This code is for **Objective-C** but you can use same in swift after converting it to swift syntax.

I hope this will help you.

Try code below.

```
-(void) uploadVideoOnFacebook 
{
    NSURL *pathURL;
    NSData *videoData;


    pathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.strUploadVideoURL];
    videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.strUploadVideoURL]];

    NSString *strDesc;
    strDesc = txtCaption.text;

    NSDictionary *videoObject = @{@"title": @"application Name",@"description": strDesc,[pathURL absoluteString]: videoData};
    FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:videoObject HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
           if (!error)
               NSLog("Success");
           else
               NSLog("Error");
    }];
}
```

Comment: Looking for swift if you could translate? Thanks

Comment: I can't because i haven't done any project on swift language.

Comment: @AngryDuck - have you tried to convert above code to swift?