# Post Video to Facebook with swift SDK

Tags: facebook, swift4

I have been trying to figure this out all day and yesterday night, but no luck. I can confirm that the LinkShareContent works but when I try to share a video file. It gives me an error code "reserved" but nothing else.

This is the code for the link

```
var content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
showShareDialog(content)
```

and this is the code for the video that does not work at all.

```
 let video = Video(url: url)
 var content = VideoShareContent(video: video, previewPhoto: Photo(image: inProgressItem.firstImage, userGenerated: true))
 showShareDialog(content)
```

This will show the share Sheet on the controller

```
  Func showShareDialog<C: ContentProtocol>(_ content: C, mode: ShareDialogMode = .shareSheet) {
        let dialog = ShareDialog(content: content)
        dialog.presentingViewController = self
        dialog.mode = mode

        do{
            try dialog.show()
        }
        catch (let error){
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I have confirmed that the video is on the local path and I'm testing the app on iPhone 8 11.1.2

Comment: have you had a chance to find out how to fix it? facing the same issue... the only idea to fix is to try using `GraphSharer` but haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had exactly the same issue. It was working for `LinkShareContent` but didn't work for `VideoShareContent`.

The solution:
Make sure you are getting the right `URL` for the video. The right one is the URL for key `"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"` from `info` dictionary that comes from `UIImagePickerController` delegate method.

Working Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    if let videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL {
        let video = Video(url: videoURL)
        let content = VideoShareContent(video: video)
        let dialog = ShareDialog(content: content)
        dialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
        dialog.mode = .native
        dialog.presentingViewController = self
        do {
            try dialog.show()
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Extra info: initially I did not use this key "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" cuz it's [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerreferenceurl?language=objc). Apple advises using UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset instead. But the URL from there also returns `reserved` error. Another try was to use key "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL", but it also didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I use `PHPickerViewController` instead of `UIPickerController`.

```
private lazy var videoPickerController: PHPickerViewController = {
        let photoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: photoLibrary)
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        configuration.filter = .any(of: [.videos])
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = self
        return picker
    }()
```

Then using `PHAsset` for initialisation `ShareVideo(videoAsset:)`.

```
private func facebookShare(content: Content) {
        guard let schemaUrl = URL(string: "fb://") else {
            return
        }
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(schemaUrl) {
            let video = ShareVideo(videoAsset: content)
            let content = ShareVideoContent()
            content.video = video
            let dialog = ShareDialog(
                viewController: self,
                content: content,
                delegate: self
            )
            
            do {
                try dialog.validate()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                presentAlert(message: (error.userInfo[ErrorDeveloperMessageKey] as? String) ?? error.localizedDescription)
            } catch {
                presentAlert(message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
            if dialog.canShow {
                dialog.show()
            }
        } else {
            presentAlert(message: "FB app not installed")
        }
    }
```

And `PHPickerViewControllerDelegate` looks something like this (I always select only 1 asset that's why I use `fetchResult.firstObject`)

```
 func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        
        let identifiers = results.compactMap(\.assetIdentifier)
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: identifiers, options: nil)
        guard let videoAsset = fetchResult.firstObject else { return }
}
```

This solution works for iOS 14 and higher and if on your device Facebook app installed.
Also before upload video I login via FB.