# Share video to Facebook via Graph iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I try to upload video to Facebook using Graph API.
But always see error message

> (#100) No permission to publish the video.

Facebook app has Development mode. I created test user there. My role is admin. FB access token is valid.

Here my code here:

```
private func upload(url: URL) {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return }
        let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
        connection.delegate = self
        var items: [String: Any] = [:]
        items["title"] = "Test title from api"
        items["\(url.absoluteString)"] = data
        let keys = ["value" : "EVERYONE"]
        items["privacy"] = keys
        
        let request = GraphRequest(graphPath:  "me/videos", parameters: items, httpMethod: .post)
        
        connection.add(request) { reqconnection, anyInfo, error in
            print(reqconnection)
            print(anyInfo)
            print(error)
        }
        
        connection.start()
    }
```

I saw a lot of questions about it, but mostly they are too old and don't work for me.

1. [Share video to FB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35611241/11079607)
2. From thread FB Developers [here](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2155365864590592/) - the same error, but they didn't find solution
3. Also check this [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/user/videos) - doesn't work

Also I'm a bit confused what docs are right for post video in Facebook.
Because in docs I see

> The Video API allows you to publish Videos on Pages and Groups. Publishing on Users is not supported.

but also in another docs see Graph API with path `me/videos`. So it confused me a bit.

What docs are correct for my case:

1. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing)
2. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/user/videos)

From docs I see that

> Your app should manage permissions as follows:
> Graph API Requests - Before you send Graph API requests, you should check for necessary permissions and request them if needed.

Where can I find permission `publish_actions`?

Please help to figure out how to fix that.

I only can upload via `ShareDialog`. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71435371/11079607) and docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/)

Comment: The Facebook docs you link to specifically say: "This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v3.2.".

Comment: @WizKid ok, and what about other docs? I mean about this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing ?

Comment: What about it, it says right there on top of that page, _"The Video API allows you to publish Videos on Pages and Groups. Publishing on Users is not supported."_

Comment: @CBroe thanks, but via `ShareDialog` I can share video on User. So upload via Graph API and ShareDialog is different. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the dialogs give the user full control, and are pretty much the last way left to get anything posted onto a user profile.

Comment: @CBroe I got it, thanks